# Solr configuration using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, configuration, solr

I have installed Solr by following these [instructions](http://web.archive.org/web/20121016161949/http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/solr_ubuntu.html).

Tomcat is running fine, because:

```
sudo service tomcat6 status 
 * Tomcat servlet engine is running with pid 12865
```

When I am navigating to Solr on my browser using my public DNS and 8080 port, there is nothing.

Am I missing any steps? What I am doing wrong?

I got this error in Tomcat log:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot create directory: /var/lib/tomcat6/solr/data/index
```

Comment: Url for how you installed Solr is missing.

Comment: edited and added link installation link

Answer (score 1):

Check that the owner of `/var/lib/tomcat6/solr` is Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have write privilege on `/var/lib/tomcat6/solr/data/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to access Solr admin page, you should first check if Tomcat is running ok by access `http://localhost:8080`

If you are not able to see that page, it means Tomcat is not running at all, then

1) First checking your Java JDK is installed, also the correct one is being used.

```
sudo bash
which java
```

if the output is not the one you want to run tomcat, then do

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/jdk;$PATH
```

Now do `which java` to see if the correct one is being used.

2) Shut down tomcat if it's still running

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
/path/to/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

Then start it by doing

```
/path/to/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

Now try to access `http://localhost:8080`

If you can access Tomcat now, then follow the other steps to install solr from http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/solr_ubuntu.html

Comment: The solr installation URL at the end is no longer valid.